# How do I sort files and folders by date in my asp:Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, directory

I have an application that on load displays a list of files, and date modified on my server in alphabetical order according to the file name

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(strDirectory));
List<FileInfo> files = di.GetFiles().ToList();
```

How can I sort this by date modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FileSystemInfo.LastWriteTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
List<FileInfo> files = di.EnumerateFiles()
            .OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option: (do it all at once)

```
List<FileInfo> files = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(strDirectory)).GetFiles()
                    .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
                    .Select(f => f.Name)
                    .ToList();
```

Tips: you can type a dot after each extension method to explore more options for future references. (i.e. instead of OrderByDescending(), you can use OrderBy();
you can just do a .ToList() after ordering without doing .Select(f => f.Name) if you like)